# Open a website in AWS SageMaker Notebooks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Amazon SageMaker and running a notebook instance in it. In my notebook instance I created a conda_python3 file and try to running the following command (which is running on my local machine):

```
import os
for i  in range(1):
    os.system("start \"\" https://google.com")
os.system("taskkill /im msedge.exe /f")
```

This should open and close the google website. What configurations or adjustments I am missing on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Your local machine must be Windows.  There is no `start` command in the linux shell, if I am not mistaken.